# Class 'BingAds\Proxy\ClientProxy' not found

Tags: php

I'm trying to authenticate with Bing Ads API, but I'm getting this error:

Fatal error: Class 'BingAds\Proxy\ClientProxy' not found in /../Bing Ads API in PHP/PHP/Bing Ads API in PHP/v10/KeywordsAds.php on line 53

This is my code:

```
include 'bingads\v10\CampaignManagementClasses.php';
include 'bingads\ClientProxy.php'; 
// Specify the BingAds\Proxy objects that will be used.
use BingAds\Proxy\ClientProxy;

// Disable WSDL caching.

ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", "0");
ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_ttl", "0");

// Specify your credentials.

$UserName = "xxxx";
$Password = "xxxx";
$DeveloperToken = "xxx";
$CustomerId = "xxxx";
$AccountId = "xxxx";

// Campaign Management WSDL
$wsdl = "https://campaign.api.bingads.microsoft.com/Api/Advertiser/CampaignManagement/V10/CampaignManagementService.svc?singleWsdl";
$proxy = ClientProxy::ConstructWithAccountAndCustomerId($wsdl, $UserName, $Password, $DeveloperToken, $AccountId, null, null);
```

I'm executing it on this directory:

```
/../Bing Ads API in PHP/PHP/Bing Ads API in PHP/v10
```

And this is bingads\ClientProxy.php

```
<?php

namespace BingAds\Proxy;

use \DOMDocument;
use \DOMXPath;
use \SoapHeader;
use \SoapClient;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use composer to install bing adds -

https://github.com/CPCStrategy/bing-ads-sdk-php

This way you will not need to "include" those files like that and will be able to take advantage of auto loading which will include them for you.